# How to create a custom template system in PHP

Tags: php, templates, template-engine

I want to use a custom template system in my php application,

What I want is I want to keep away my php codes from design, I would like to use a tpl file for  designs and a php file for php codes

I dont want to use any ready maid scripts. Can any one point out some links link or useful info how to build a php templating system to achieve this

Thank you

Comment: If you don't know how to write them - look how some mature (`smarty` for example) of them is written or don't be so optimistic and just take one (i offer you to look at `mustache`)

Comment: http://phptemplatinglanguage.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I do it is to create a template file(.tpl if you wish) and insert markers which will be replaced with str_replace in PHP. The code will look something like this:

For template.tpl file

```
<body>
  <b>Something: </b> <!-- marker -->
</body>
```

For the PHP

```
$template = file_get_contents('template.tpl');
$some_data = 'Some Text'; //could be anything as long as the data is in a variable
$template = str_replace('<!-- marker -->', $some_data, $template);
echo $template;
```

That's it in a nutshell but it can get a lot more complex. The marker can be anything as long as it's unique.

Comment: that is absolutely unusable in the real world.

Comment: at least you will need blocks to make it usable

Comment: Please explain. I use this method every day and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to keep away my php codes from design, I would like to use a tpl file for designs

...and mix your tpl codes with "design"!
what's the difference then? :)

PHP itself is efficient templating system.
And nowadays most developers agreed that dividing your PHP code to *business logic* part and *display logic* part is most preferable way.
It can be very limited subset of PHP of course. You will need an output operator (`<?=$var?>`) one, a condition `<? if(): ?>...<? endif ?>`, a loop `<? foreach(): ?>...<? endforeach ?>` and include.

An example of such a template:

```
<table>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?> 
  <tr>
    <td><b><?=$row['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?=$row['date'] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><?=$row['body'] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <? if ($row['answer']): ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 valign="top">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><b>Answer: </b></td>
          <td><?=$row['answer'] ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <? endif ?>
  <? if($admin): ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>
  <? if($row['del']): ?>
      <a href="/gb/?action=undelete&id=<?=$row['id']?>">show</a>
  <? else: ?>
      <a href="/gb/?action=delete&id=<?=$row['id']?>">hide</a>
  <? endif ?>
      <a href="/gb/?action=edit&id=<?=$row['id']?>">edit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <? endif ?>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 Yep, this is a good answer. The only thing I'd add is to mention `short_tags` and that this won't work with it switched off.

Comment: @alex there are many things than won't work if switched off. display_errors, PDO support, mod_rewrite - anything. That's not a reason to mention it. That's the purpose of such a configuration option - to be switched on and off. Nothing bad or even worth mentioning I'd say.